# VB6 Hex in a string - literal value woes

Tags: vb6, hex

I'm trying to store the literal ascii value of hex FFFF which in decimal is 65535 and is ÿ when written out in VB6. I want to store this value in a buffer which is defined by:

```
Type HBuff
   txt As String * 16
End Type

Global WriteBuffer As HBuff
```

in the legacy code I inherited.

I want to do something like `WriteBuffer.txt = Asc(hex$(-1))` but VB6 stores it as `70`
I need to store this value, `ÿ` in the string, even though it is not printable.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is.

If you want to store character number 255 in a string, then do so:

```
WriteBuffer.txt = Chr$(255)
```

Be warned though that the result depends on the current locale.
`ChrW$(255)` does not, but it may yield not the character you want.

For the reference, the code you used returns ASCII code of the first character of the textual hex representation of the number `-1`. `Hex(-1)` is `FFFF` when `-1` is typed as `Integer` (which it is by default), so you get the ASCII code of letter `F`, which is `70`.